# Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and double

Tags: c#

Apologies for the ignorance, I'm very new at this, and I'm getting the Following errors.

I also placed comments where lines 56 and 63 are

Line 56 error - CS0019 Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and double

Line 63 error - Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

```
{
class Savings : Account
{
    //property
    private double interestrate;

    //constructor
    public Savings()
    {

    }

    public Savings(string AccountName, int AccountNumber, decimal balance, double interestrate)
    {
        setAccountName(AccountName);
        setAccountNumber(AccountNumber);
        setBalance(balance);
        setinterestrate(interestrate);
    }

    //setter
    public void setinterestrate(double interestratepassedin)
    {
        if (interestrate > 0)
        {
            interestrate = interestratepassedin;

        }
        else
        {
            interestrate = 0;
        }

    }




    //getter
    public double getinterestrate()
    {
        return interestrate;
    }


    //method to calculate interest
    public void calculateinterest()
    {
        //line 56 below
        return getBalance() * getinterestrate();

    }

    public override void printaccount()
    {
        base.printaccount();
        //line 63 below
        Console.WriteLine(Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", getAccountName(), getAccountNumber(), getBalance(), interestrate));

    }

}
}
```

Comment: `setAccountName`, `setAccountNumber`? What is this, Java? Whoever is teaching you to code like that, is not a very proficient c# developer

Comment: Change the return type of `calculateinterest()` function from `void` to `double`. Actually `void` means nothing to return and you are trying to return a `double` value from a `void` function.

Comment: `void` methods doesn't have return type, you can't use `return` statements there. If `GetBalance` is a decimal (I think you're coming from Java world which uses *camelCase* method names & getter-setter methods) then the multiplication is invalid when second operator is a `double` (change to `decimal` for both).

Answer (score 0):

Your `calculateinterest()` method's return type is `void` but it returns a value.
Change the return type to appropriate datatype instead of `void`.

looks like `getBalance()` returns `decimal`.
you can convert interestrate to decimal and make `getinterestrate()` to return `decimal` instead of `double`.

you can change `getinterestrate()` as below :-

```
public decimal getinterestrate()
{
     return (decimal)interestrate;
}
```

Comment: This solves only one of the issues

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix the decimal and double errors, but I'm still having issues on the printaccount method "cannot convert from void to bool

Comment: Please check the getAccountName() method is having a proper return type.

Comment: getAccountName() is returning a string, which is what it's supposed to do

Comment: You have to provide detailed code including the Account class so that I can help you with the issue.